# Pagination Class in Third Party Module

Tags: pagination

I'm new to EE and I'm having problems using the Pagination Class. I've created a custom module and have the following method in my mod file. The pagination is rendering on the template fine and the URLs look fine (mydomain/series/pagination_test/P24) but the results are not changing as I navigate the pagination.

```
public function pagination_test() {

    $this->EE->load->library('pagination');
    $pagination = $this->EE->pagination->create();
    $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata = $pagination->prepare(ee()->TMPL->tagdata);
    $tagdata = $this->EE->TMPL->tagdata;
    $results = $this->EE->gt_model->pagination_test_data();

    foreach($results as $row)
    {
        $variables[] = array(
          'alt_title' => $row['alt_title']
          );
    }

    if ($pagination->paginate === TRUE)
    {
        $total_items = count($results);
        $per_page = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('limit');
        $status = $pagination->build($total_items, $per_page);
    }

    $this->return_data = $this->EE->TMPL->parse_variables( $tagdata, $variables );
    $this->return_data = $pagination->render($this->return_data);

    return $this->return_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The step you're missing is actually filtering your query/dataset by the `offset` generated by the Pagination class. (Usually this is used inside a database query, but you can also just use it to slice your array.)

```
if ($pagination->paginate === TRUE)
{
    $total_items = count($results);
    $per_page = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('limit');
    $pagination->build($total_items, $per_page);

    // The important bit
    $variables = array_slice($variables, $pagination->offset, $per_page);
}
```

Comment: If you were doing this within the query instead, would you just pass $pagination->offset in the offset() method of the query builder?